# fread not advancing the pointer

Tags: c, file-io, fread

I am working with `fread()` in C. I am trying to read content of a binary file name **pds_demo.bin** but somehow my `fread` function is not advancing. I checked the returned value of `fread()` in gdb it is returning 0.

There are totally 3 files I am working with **pds_functions.c**, **pds_test.c** and the **pds_demo.bin** (contains the data to be read).

**pds_test.c** is calling a function named `pds_search_by_key()` in **pds_functions.c** to check for a particular. This function checks the content of demo file and returns the status whether the record is present or not. I have included all the files below.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**pds_test.c**:

```
void test_search() {
    int status;
    struct Contact c3;
    int key;
    key = 101;
    status = pds_search_by_key(key, &c3);
    if (status != PDS_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pds_search_by_key failed for key %d: errorcode %d\n", key, status);
    } else {
        printContact(&c3);
    }
    key = 102;
    status = pds_search_by_key(key, &c3);
    if (status != PDS_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pds_search_by_key failed for key %d: errorcode %d\n", key, status);
    } else {
        printContact(&c3);
    }
    key = 1020000;
    status = pds_search_by_key(key, &c3);
    if (status != PDS_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pds_search_by_key failed for key %d: errorcode %d\n", key, status);
    } else {
        printContact(&c3);
    }
}
```

**pds_functions.c**:

```
int pds_search_by_key(int key, struct Contact *c) {

    fseek(repo_fptr, 0L, 0);

    if (pdsInfo.repo_status == 1) {
        while (!feof(repo_fptr)) {
            fread(c, sizeof(struct Contact), 1, repo_fptr);
            if (c->contact_id == key) {
                return PDS_SUCCESS;
            }
        }
        return PDS_REC_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    return PDS_REPO_NOTOPEN;
}
```

**pds_demo.bin**:

```
101 Contact #1 Phone #1 Email #1 102 Contact #2 Phone #2 Email #2 102 Contact #2 Phone #2 Email #2
```

There is also one structure which define the structure Contact.

```
struct Contact {
    int contact_id;
    char cname[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char mphone[MAX_PHONE_LEN];
    char email[MAX_EMAIL_LEN];
};
```

Also when I debug the program using gdb the content of *c is as follows:

```
(gdb) p *c
$1 = {contact_id = 540094513, cname = "Contact #1 Phone #1 Email #1 102 
Contact #2 Phone ", mphone = "#2 Email #2", 
  email = " 102 Contact #2 Phone #2 Email #2 \377\377\177\000\000\t\t@\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}
```

Comment: [`while (!feof(...))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: What changes do i need to make?

Comment: A point to note is that `fread` reads `c` which is a type of `struct Contact`, but the `size_t` argument is `1`.

Comment: `fread(c, 1, 1, repo_fptr);` reads a single byte, and you don't check that it was successful.  If `c` is not a `char` — and it isn't — you need something more like `if (fread(c, sizeof(*c), 1, repo_fptr) != 1) { /* oops — nothing read */ }`.

Comment: my bad actually i was just doing trial and error stuff and forgot to change the code before uploading here. Anyway i tried with fread(c,sizeof(struct Contact),1,repo_fptr) but still the result is same.

Comment: I suggest the loop should be like `while(fread(c, sizeof *c, 1, repo_fptr) == 1) { if(c->contact_id == key) { return PDS_SUCCESS; }}`

Comment: Notice also that `fread` will return `0` if it cannot read one full record

Comment: It seems that you are writing as text without using `fwrite`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are right i was actually using fprintf(). But problem still persists. fread() is not advancing the pointer.

Comment: It is necessary to match the format of writing and reading.

Comment: Your reading loop is incorrect: Learn why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are major problems in your code:

- Your reading loop is incorrect, lean why here: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)
- You are reading fixed length structures from a file, you must read and write the file in binary mode, `fopen` must be passed `"rb"` or `"wb"` respectively to open the file in binary mode.

Provided the file is opened in binary mode, the reading loop could be modified this way:

```
int pds_search_by_key(int key, struct Contact *c) {

    fseek(repo_fptr, 0L, 0);

    if (pdsInfo.repo_status == 1) {
        while (fread(c, sizeof(*c), 1, repo_fptr) == 1) {
            if (c->contact_id == key) {
                return PDS_SUCCESS;
            }
        }
        return PDS_REC_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    return PDS_REPO_NOTOPEN;
}
```